# Wordpress search form problem: There is no space between text lines in search results

Tags: search

I use Astra and Elementor pro. I put in search form on page. It shows results but the text that comes up is scrambled, all in one row. I can´t seem to be able to change space between text lines when it comes to search results. I can change for paragraphs and space between lines on pages but not search results.

I have done this:
Cleared all cache: browser's cache, other plugins' cache.
Deactivated all plugins apart from Elementor and Elementor Pro.
Switched the theme and it did not make any difference.

Comment: Sounds like a theme problem, since the search.php template is used for search results. Have you contacted the theme support?